# Flutter - onStepContinue called automatically on build

Tags: flutter, function, build, navigation, widget

I'm using Stepper widget to make a form for profile creation. In the `onStepContinue` method, if its the last step I put the function call for sending data to backend and added the navigation route to home page to its `.whenComplete` method.

```
body: Stepper(
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
        currentStep: _activeCurrentStep,
        steps: stepList(),

        onStepContinue: () async {
          final isLastStep = _activeCurrentStep == stepList().length - 1;

          if (isLastStep) {
            final authenticationNotifier =
                Provider.of<AuthenticationNotifier>(context, listen: false);
            var userEmail =
                await authenticationNotifier.fetchUserEmail(context: context);
            var profileName = profileNameController.text;
            var profileBio = profileBioController.text;

            await profileNotifier(false)
                .createProfile(
                    context: context,
                    profileDTO: ProfileDTO(
                      useremail: userEmail,
                      profile_name: profileName,
                      profile_bio: profileBio,
                    ))
                .whenComplete(
                    () => Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(HomeRoute));
          } else if (_activeCurrentStep < (stepList().length - 1)) {
            setState(() {
              _activeCurrentStep += 1;
            });
          }
        },

        onStepCancel: _activeCurrentStep == 0
            ? null
            : () {
                setState(() {
                  _activeCurrentStep -= 1;
                });
              },

        onStepTapped: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _activeCurrentStep = index;
          });
        },
      ),
```

The stepper widget is in a page/scaffold of its own. Its loaded from `onPressed` of a button in authview.dart file.

```
                  onPressed: () {
                    authenticationNotifier.signup(
                        context: context,
                        useremail: signupEmailController.text,
                        userpassword: signupPasswordController.text);
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pushNamed(ProfileCreationRoute);
                  },
```

The problem is that as soon as I press the sign up button in authview the stepper page shows up for a fraction of a second and loads the homepage without letting me create the profile. I need it to just show the stepper and go to homepage only after I fill the profile details and click submit.

I thought `.whenComplete` would be called only when the button is pressed and its parent function finishes its work, and in this case I guess the problem is somehow with the stepper widget itself.

I also added `&& profileNameController.text.isNotEmpty` in the `if (isLastStep)` condition but it doesn't work. Clicking on sign up button is bypassing the stepper widget and going to homeview as soon as stepper finishes building itself.

I don't understand what's going on. Please help.

EDIT

The createProfile function in notifier is

```
class ProfileNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final ProfileAPI _profileAPI = ProfileAPI();

  Future createProfile({
    required BuildContext context,
    required ProfileDTO profileDTO,
  }) async {
    try {
      await _profileAPI.createProfile(profileDTO);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

And the API call that sends data to node backend is

```
class ProfileAPI {
  final client = http.Client();
  final headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  };

  // Create new Profile
  Future createProfile(ProfileDTO profileDTO) async {
    final String subUrl = "/profile/create/${profileDTO.useremail}";
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(APIRoutes.BaseURL + subUrl);
    try {
      final http.Response response = await client.post(uri,
          body: jsonEncode(profileDTO.toJson()), headers: headers);

      final statusCode = response.statusCode;
      final body = response.body;

      if (statusCode == 200) {
        return body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 2
On changing `whenComplete` to `then` the linter shows this error.

```
The argument type 'Future<Object?> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(dynamic)'. dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

What to do? Please help

Comment: I apologize for this question. I didn't check the route in the signup method. That's what was redirecting to the home screen. The code above with the stepper widget works fine on itself. I've flagged it for deletion by moderators.

Comment: The thing is I put one route in the authview widget and another route in the signup method of auth notifier. I feel so stupid. Well, learning by making mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

So from what is see is you are using the whencomplete, but the reason that's happening is the when complete will run every time either its and failure or success. So what i think is you should be using the then Method instead on whencomplete
which will only run in success condition.

Comment: When I changed it to `.then` linter is showing the error `The argument type 'Future<Object?> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(dynamic)'`

Comment: Just what to ask are you returning ant thing from the createprofile function or its void return.

Comment: I edited question to add the other code as well. I'm just a beginner so I don't completely understand things. Please see it and advise.

Comment: just want to ask does the signup work properly, are you hiting the signup api with 200 response.

Comment: yes, the sign up works and I'm taken directly to homepage without being able to enter profile details